# Parallel for-loop with SharedArray

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, julia, memory-efficient

I would like to have the most time and memory  efficient load balanced application of an operation to each column of a SharedArray producing corresponding columns that are modifying in-place a pre-allocated output SharedArray. How should I improve the following code ?

```
using SharedArrays, Distributed

nCores = length(Sys.cpu_info())
addprocs(nCores - 1);

@everywhere using SharedArrays, Distributed

@everywhere addConstant = 10000;

@everywhere function divideColByMeanConstant(x)
    return (x ./ mean(x)) .+ addConstant
end

inputMAT = SharedArray(rand(10000,20000))
outputMAT = SharedArray(Array{Float64,2}(undef, size(inputMAT)))

function Array2ArrayColumnwise_forloop!(output::SharedArray{Float64,2},operation::Function, input::SharedArray{Float64,2}, rowRange::Array{Int64,1},colRange::Array{Int64,1})

    @async @distributed for colInd in colRange
        @views output[rowRange,colInd] = operation(input[rowRange, colInd]) 
    end
end
     

rowRange  = [1,4,6,8,10,15];
colRange  = [1,4,5, 6, 7,10,15];

Array2ArrayColumnwise_forloop!(outputMAT,divideColByMeanConstant, inputMAT, rowRange,colRange)
```

Thank you in advance